# VB6: Error 91 when adding data to object

Tags: vb6

In code [VB6], I'm searching in a collection for a specific data. Fam87 comes from a text file.

```
Function cumplefam(Fam87FO As String, rFamn1 As String, rFamn2 As String, rFam87 As String) As Boolean
    Dim objfam As Tfamilias
    Dim c1, c2, c3 As String

    **objfam = getfamilia(Fam87FO)**

    If rFamn1 = "" Then
        c1 = "OK"
    Else
        If InStr(objfam.cFamn1, rFamn1) > 0 Then
            c1 = "OK"
        Else
            c1 = "NO OK"
        End If
    End If

    If rFamn2 = "" Then
        c2 = "OK"
    Else
        If InStr(objfam.cFamn2, rFamn2) > 0 Then
            c2 = "OK"
        Else
            c2 = "NO OK"
        End If
    End If

    If rFam87 = "" Then
        c3 = "OK"
    Else
        If InStr(objfam.cFam87, rFam87) > 0 Then
            c3 = "OK"
        Else
            c3 = "NO OK"
        End If
    End If

    If c1 = "OK" And c2 = "OK" And c3 = "OK" Then
        cumplefam = True
    Else
        cumplefam = False
    End If

End Function
```

The problem comes when getfamilia runs:

```
Function getfamilia(cFam As String) As Tfamilias
    On Error Resume Next
    Set getfamilia = Nothing
    getfamilia = colfamilias(cFam)
End Function
```

Running it step-by-step does give me the data I want, but when it hits the End Function it shows:

Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

I'm inexperienced in VB, so I don't really catch what my error is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `colfamilias` has actually been initialized, for a return value that is an object, you must use `Set`:

```
Function getfamilia(cFam As String) As Tfamilias
    On Error Resume Next
    Set getfamilia = Nothing
    Set getfamilia = colfamilias(cFam) '// change this line
End Function
```

And in your call to the function:

```
Set objfam = getfamilia(Fam87FO)
```

Comment: Yeah, is initialized at the very beggining with other collections (Public colfamilias As Collection). I tried with Set at the beginning like you said, and got the same error.

Comment: You also have to `Set objfam...` in your call to the function.

Comment: Thanks, it just run without a problem!